# php mysql: I'm trying to retrieve data(rowB) from a table where rowA=something and rowC=something

Tags: php, mysql

I'm sure you can tell i'm new to PHP, I'm building a chore reward application from scratch for practice. Here's the query. Thanks for the help.

```
$amt_query = "select `chore_worth` from chores
              where child_id=".$_GET['kids_id']."
              and chore_name=".$_SESSION['choreName'].""
```

Comment: So, what is the problem? Your query seems ok.

Answer (score 1):

it will work, but before that , please check your code since it is vurnerable to SQL injections.

```
"SELECT chore_worth FROM chores
 WHERE child_id = '" . $_GET['kids_id'] . "' 
 and chore_name = '" . $_SESSION['choreName'] . "' ";
```

Comment: Thanks, I see my issue. I've been googling all day and could not think of the correct google slang ("multiple conditions"). Literal just found it...lol Thanks again.